# Applying WebGL filter on HD Images cuts the image (fabric V2-beta-6)

Tags: image, fabricjs

Currently working with **fabric 2.0.6** to apply filters on HD images. I need to apply the filters in least amount of time. for that purpose i am using the webGL method to apply filters as explained [here (fabric.js demo)](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters). If you apply it on images with size <= 1 MB it works perfectly fine but with image size greater than that, filter does apply fairly well but it cuts the image in doing so. Attaching the test Image and applying greyscale filter for reference

Original Image(size 1.90 MB)
[image: OrignalImage]

How it appears before applying filter
[image: Before]

How it appears after applying greyScale filter
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please if you refer to changelog and explanation:

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-filters

instead of looking at a demo application, you will notice that the doc talks about a `fabric.textureSize` property.

The limit is unrelated to the size in Megabytes, but is related to pixel size.

It is set up at 2048, size as base setting, to accomodate most of old hardware and giving you a max 2048x2048 filter size.

Rise this value before starting your app to the maximum size you think you want to support. 4096 for example.

If you go over 5000 you will probably loose support for ie11.

There are 2 limits you have to be aware of:
Max canvas size in the browser and max texture size in the hardware of the laptop your user is using.

Comment: thanks for your help. If i may ask, How can i calculate what filter size is suitable for an image of 2800 x 1800 dimension image? Is there a formula to to predict the suitable filter size for an image?

Comment: You have to pick up 2800. The texture is created as big as the image, while the canvas to hold it is create square. Probably because i did not wand to insert 2 parameters, there is really no specific reason behind it. So your canvas for webgl will be 2800x2800

Comment: I increased the fabric.textureSize to 4096, just as you instructed but still Image gets cut away